# What causes Google Reader to think an item is updated in an RSS feed?

Tags: rss

I'm generating an RSS feed from my blog. I'm using [node-rss](http://github.com/dylang/node-rss). When I make a minor edit to one the posts listed in the feed, Google Reader lists the item as unread, even though I marked it as read a week ago.

My RSS feed contains `title`, `description`, `link`, `guid` and `pubDate` elements for each item. For `guid`, I'm just using the canonical URL to the item. The `pubDate` element is the date/time that the entry was first published, rather than the time of the last edit.

The feed itself contains `lastBuildDate`, which is set to the time that the RSS feed was generated (i.e. when it was requested).

As far as I can tell, there's nothing in the RSS feed that flags the item as being changed. So why does Google Reader think that the item has been updated, and why does it show it as unread again?

Does it look at the content (which has changed)? If so, can I do something in the RSS feed to mark this as a minor update, thus preventing Google Reader from showing it as unread?

Comment: OT - Google Reader is going away in July.

Comment: That's still 3 months away, and I'd be interested to know if I'm doing something wrong, so that other RSS readers will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

If, in Google Reader, you mouse over the date in the top-right of each post, you'll see that it has "Received" and "Published" dates.

"Received" appears to be when the Google Reader server saw the new content, whereas "Published" comes from the feed itself.

Google Reader appears to use the "Received" date to decide whether something is new.

So, to get the correct behaviour

- Don't put anything in the feed that's older than (say) 6 months.
- Limit the feed XML to the most-recent 10 or so items.

Of course, the second could imply the first...